# Physics Fluid Simulation Not Working

Tags: physics, fluid-simulation

I've downloaded Blender for the first time, version 2.90.0.
I've watched multiple videos on how to create a fluid simulation.
I've replicated the steps and for some reason, it doesn't simulate when I press play.
I've tried the rigid body simulator and it works just fine.
Am I missing a setting or something? In the videos they were using blender 2.8, which had a "bake" feature. I couldn't find that option in 2.9. Could it be my computer isn't fast enough to create the simulation, so nothing appears?

Steps and result: https://drive.google.com/file/d/19VfqVp6HtgplkoIHXLBo2EMv6jsafQCu/view?usp=sharing
Rigid body working: https://drive.google.com/file/d/10j57Pcr2y-wMr6OdAaD0X8Oaie6lmp3S/view?usp=sharing

Comment: it could be a lot of things , baking option would not be there if you are in the replay mode in the cache , or if you didn't add a domain , or your domain type is a gas but the inflow object is gas , please check these 3 things and if then also you have the same problem , then upload the file on https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: It was the Cache Type. It was set to replay. I changed it to All, and it worked after caching. Thank you

Comment: Very common confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed Cache > Type to All, and Bake options appeared.
Baked, then ran the simulation without a problem.